# Can I do anything with the dead men sending Morse code messages?

Tags: resistance-fall-of-man

Once in a while, I've come across a dead soldier ingame whose backpack is sending out a message in Morse code. Is there anything that I can do ingame regarding decoding or interpreting these messages? I'm currently in Manchester, and I haven't found anything that would let me decode the Morse code ingame so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the dead soldiers, there's usually a morse code message playing on the pause screen that changes on each level.

There doesn't seem to be any way in-game to decode these messages.  They are just a tiny bit of extra story/plot color to the game, and don't really give you any gameplay hints or tips.

There's a complete list of the codes and their decoded messages on the [Resistance Wikia.](http://resistance.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Ops_Morse_Code)